# Losing scope between angular modules using ng-view

Tags: angularjs, scope, ng-view

I seem to be losing scope on my angular controller when I am trying to abstract my Angularjs modules.

It works fine if i use my app module, but as soon as I change the home.js module to app.layout, $scope no longer works.

Can anybody spot an issue here?

_Layout.html (left out includes and head)

```
<body class="docs-body" ng-app="app">
<div layout="column" ng-cloak>
    <section layout="row" flex>
        <div ng-include="'App/layout/sidenav.html'"></div>
        <md-content class="_md layout-column flex" layout="column" flex="">
            <div ng-include="'App/layout/toolbar.html'"></div>
            <div class="container body-content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
```

@RenderBody() brings up Index.html

```
<!-- this is where content will be injected -->
<div ng-view></div>
```

Home.html

```
<div>
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

My app.js

```
angular.
.module('app', [
        'app.core',
        'app.layout',
    ]);
```

})();

layout.module.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.layout', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngAria'
]);
```

})();

core.module.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.core', [
    'ngRoute'
]);
```

})();

and route.js:

```
angular.module('app.core')
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'App/layout/home.html',
            controller: 'home'
        });// End routeprovider
    })// end config
```

And Finally the culprit... Home.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

console.log('registering controller home before Angular');

angular
    .module('app.layout')
    .controller('home', home);

home.$inject = ['$scope']; 

function home($scope) {
    console.log('registering controller home');
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
}
```

})();

Now, When i have

```
.module('app);
.controller('home', home);
```

on home.js, the $scope.message displays

```
'Everyone come and see how good I look!'
```

but if i have

```
.module('app.layout')
.controller('home', home);
```

it displays

```
{{message}}
```

I know I'm losing scope somehow here, but I cant figure out how to fix it! Do I need to declare the controller again outside of the Router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather frustrating. Using Visual Studio's Bundle config, It was adding the home.js file in before it compiled the module files. In doing so, when it tried to build and register the controller, It couldn't find the module. solution was to build all modules first then build controllers by specifying build order in the bundle config.

Answer (score 0):

I think Angular not able to get your `home` controller. You should inject `app.layout` in `app.core` module.

```
  angular.module('app.core', ['app.layout'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'App/layout/home.html',
            controller: 'home'
        });// End routeprovider
    })// end config


angular.
.module('app.layout',[]).controller();
```

Comment: I tried injecting app.layout into the core module but it still doesn't build the controller when I debug. I also tried injecting core into the layout but it still doesn't build it. 

It does seem to not be able to get to the home controller but I'm still trying to figure out the dependencies on the modules and how to get to others between each module.

Comment: Says the controller with name 'home' is not registered, which makes sense seeing how it cant build it

Comment: angular.module('app.layout',[]).controller();

Comment: This solution did work. however, by doing it this way, I know that its building the module in the home.js.  I have a couple controllers I'm using that need to use app.layout. I didn't include the module instantiation file earlier which i should have. 

Digging further, It seems when I try to build the controller, it cant find the module which is why building the module again there works, but doing so destroys the other controllers modules. I'll keep digging.

Comment: update your full structure of code . every one can understand your problem

Comment: I added the module files and I updated the home.js... Its logging before the angular part but fails when it try's to look up the app.layout module